# MimeMessage emails - create a "in-reply" email

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, spring-integration, mime-message

Currently , I'm recieving emails with my server(imap through spring framework)

the messages i recieve are of type MimeMessage.

lets say i now got a new email (X)

I would like to create a new MimeMessage (Y) that in it's body it will say that this email is in response (reply) to (X)

how can i do this?

p.s the (Y) message is going to be sent from a different SMTP url later on, so X and Y are not related.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create the new message and set its content to whatever you want - presumably something like...

`"In Reply To:\n\n" + copied_text_content_from_received_message;`

However, be aware that the inbound content might have various formats, including multipart (see JavaDoc for `MimeMessage.getContent()`.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [Message.reply](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Message.html#reply%28boolean%29) method.  Fill in the content of this new Message as suggested in the other answer here.